# Information about moderators in the data dump

Tags: support, data-dump, data-analysis

I was trying to look for information about the moderators of Stack Exchange Community, but I didn't find any. So can anyone please tell if there is any information available about the moderators in the data dump?

If not, how else can I download the data about it? I found some online sources like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators). But I want to download the data on my laptop.

Comment: See also http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/moderators and http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/elected-moderators. Also some sites have a [/election page](https://stackoverflow.com/election), with info about elected moderators.